# Python Split a String using more than one character while still keeping that character

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, parsing

I've seen many solutions using `re.split` but it doesn't solve my problem. I want to be able to split my string and keep some of the characters within the list... Hard to explain but here is an example:

Text:

```
'print("hello world");'
```

the result I want:

```
["print", "(", "\"", "hello", "world", "\"", ")", ";"]
```

Things like re.split would give me:

```
["print", "hello", "world"]
```

How can I get the wanted result?

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using? You can put the split part into capturing groups with `( )` and they should be included in the result as well.

Comment: Are you trying to tokenise a programming language statement? If so, there are things that can do that for you directly.

Comment: If you're trying to create a simple scripting language, it looks like what you want is a lexer. You might want to check out ANTLR if your requirements start going beyond parsing simple statements @RoeeHerzovich

Comment: I could just import a lexer, I know, but what I am doing here is trying to implement that myself, before I use a library I usually try to implement it on my own with simpler libraries unless this library is complicated such as web crawling and etc, and lexing doesn't sound so hard after you solve this problem, so yes. I do try to make a Lexer and I am aware there are tools that do that for me I just want to try and do that myself first

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this.

```
import re
text='print("hello world");'
parsed=re.findall(r'(\w+|[^a-zA-Z\s])',text)
print(parsed)
#['print', '(', '"', 'hello', 'world', '"', ')', ';']
```

`\w+` - To capture every word.

`[^a-zA-Z\s]` - To capture everything not in `[a-zA-Z]` and which is not a space.

**EDIT:** When you want to capture numbers and floats use this `re` expression `\d+\.\d+|\d+|\w+|[^a-zA-Z\s]`

`\d+` - To capture numbers
`\d+\.\d+` - To capture floats.

```
a='print("hello world",[1,2,3,4,3.15]);'
print(re.findall('\d+\.\d+|\d+|\w+|[^a-zA-Z\s]',a)
#['print', '(', '"', 'hello', 'world', '"', ',', '[', '1', ',', '2', ',', '3', ',', '4', ',', '3.15', ']', ')', ';']
```

Comment: This one is working perfectly except for one thing: if you put a float such as "1.3" you will get [1, ".", 3], I am trying to find a solution for that but if someone knows how to get through this I'd love to hear solutions

Comment: I tried changing it into: [^a-zA-Z. ] but it just made it [1, 3] and not kept it as 1.3... anybody has ideas?

Comment: @RoeeHerzovich you have write a regex expression to capture numbers and floats.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import re
re.findall(r"[A-Za-z@#]+|\S", 'print("hello world");')

Out[19]: ['print', '(', '"', 'hello', 'world', '"', ')', ';']
```

Comment: This solution works the exact same way as the last one including that other problem, thanks so much for these solutions tho :) the both of you